# How can I use Python to open command prompt, change directories then pass a string that contains a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

First time ever asking for help here so my apologies if i'm missing something relevant.

I am learning Python for data science (very new), but figured I could use it to automate some of my other work.

I'll post what I have so far, but first I'll explain what I'm trying to do:

Normally (without Python) I open up the command prompt, change directories, and then paste a string (directly into command prompt) that looks like:

"program.exe C:\file path to config file\config.cfg -extra_parameters1 -extra_parameters2 -extra_parameters3 -Mail_Date=YYYY-MM-DD"

here is what I have so far:

```
    import os

    mail_date = input(("What is the mailing date?(YYYY-MM-DD):  "))

    os.system("start cmd.exe @cmd /k CD C:\Path")

    # Next string would look like:
    # "program.exe C:\file path to config file\config.cfg -extra_parameters1 -extra_parameters2 -extra_parameters3 -Mail_Date=YYYY-MM-DD
```

So far I can run the Python script, input a mailing date as a variable, open command prompt, then change directories. I am not sure how to then pass the "program.exe..." string to the command line.

Comment: Instead of opening the command prompt and figuring out how to paste the command there, why not call the `program.exe...` command directly? Look into the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module which takes a command and a `cwd` argument for specifying the working directory.

Comment: Are you trying to create the string `"program.exe C:\file path to config file\config.cfg -extra_parameters1 -extra_parameters2 -extra_parameters3 -Mail_Date=YYYY-MM-DD` and plug it in `os.system()`?

I think you are looking for string concatenation.

Comment: Hello Thank you for the answers! I don't think i can call the program.exe directly because it requires a long string afterwards that seemingly only works in command prompt.

Comment: I found the documentation on this, from the program creator, if this helps.

https://www.flagshipsoftware.com/fsweb/command-line-options/